# How to create pdf files in memory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, itext

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdftest);
    Button Btgerar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gerarpdf);
    Btgerar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CriarPDF();
        }
    });
}
public void CriarPDF() {
    String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PDF/" + "Ficha.pdf";
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    // Create New Blank Document
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    // Create Directory in External Storage
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/PDF");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    // Create Pdf Writer for Writting into New Created Document
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

    // Open Document for Writting into document
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(txt.getText().toString()));


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Close Document after writting all content
    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF File is Created. Location : " + FILE,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Create new Page in PDF
    document.newPage();


}
}
```

I have declared in android manifest

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

and build gradle version is :

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
minSdkVersion 8
targetSdkVersion 24
```

The application can run normally, but can't create pdf file and I can't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at the subject of your question, then the answer is simple. You are creating a PDF on the file system using a `FileOutputStream`. In the subject you ask: "How to create pdf files in memory?" That is simple. iText accepts any `OutputStream`, so the answer is: use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`.

See [Using iText, generate on memory a PDF that is generated on disk instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151867/using-itext-generate-on-memory-a-pdf-that-is-generated-on-disk-instead)

```
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, out);
(...)
byte[] pdf = out.getBytes();
```

However, why would you want to create a PDF in memory on an Android device? What are you going to do with those bytes? You can't show the PDF if you only have a `byte[]`. That is explained in my answer to this question: [Display PDF document stored in a ByteArrayOutputStream (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363205/display-pdf-document-stored-in-a-bytearrayoutputstream-not-in-a-file)

You will also notice that the following question remained unanswered (because there is no answer): [How to visualize a ByteArrayOutputStream as PDF on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828268/how-to-visualize-a-bytearrayoutputstream-as-pdf-on-android)

Your question changes subject towards the end, where you write: "The application can run normally, but can't create pdf file and I can't find." This sounds as if you don't know how to write a PDF to the file system on Android. That's a different question than what you mention in the subject. That question has been answered many times before:

- [Creating PDFs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592320)
- [how to solve read only file system error in android programming with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076017)
- [How to save PDF file on Sdcard created using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329325)
- [Not able to run simple program of iText library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557339)
- [Save iText created PDF to internal memory as MODE_WORLD_READABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697220)