# Save a PDF file using ITextPDF

Tags: java, android, itext, fileoutputstream, itext7

I am using ITextPDF to create a PDF.The PDF is created in android. I would NOT like to save the pdf to the local storage of the android device, instead I would like to save it to a variable, like File file; or something similar, or directly convert it to a string and then save that value to a database.

This is where I declare the File variable(this can change)

```
File file;
```

This is the button that executes the pdf creation.

```
PDFTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PDF();
        }
    });
```

This is the method to create the PDF

```
public void PDF()
    {
        try {
            Image img = Image.getInstance(IMAGES[0]);
            Document document = new Document(img);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Example"));
            document.close();
        }catch (DocumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The FileOutputStream requires a location which I just made file. If the file is correct, how can I display the values from that file object.

Comment: Well just use PdfReader http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html

Comment: That is iText 5 documentation, OP asked about iText 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create pdf files in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947247/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-memory)

Answer (score 1):

In the iText 7 API documentation of [`PdfWriter`](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter.html), you can read that the constructor takes an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). This can be any `OutputStream`, like a  [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) or a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

See also the duplicate question [How to create pdf files in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947247/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-memory).